# Entity Framework Update Statement

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.3

I'm trying to update a specific record based off of a users selection.  Regarding Entity Framework syntax, I'm not very familiar.  Is it possible to achieve this SQL statement in Entity FrameWork?

Thank you!

```
  update Table1
  set Colum1='1'
  where Column2='1234567'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var record = _db.Table1.where(r => r.Column2 == '1234567');
record.Column1 = '1'
_db.SaveChanges();
```

where _db is the Entity Framework DbContext class...

HTH.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Linq Version:

```
Table1Entity entity = from e in dbContext.Table1Entitys
                      where e.Column2 = '1234567'
                      select e

entity.Column1 = '1';
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

And looks like Sunny has the [Lambda version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10354126/209259).

However, neither this nor Sunny's answer produces the exact SQL because they both actually produce a SELECT and an UPDATE:

```
SELECT <all columns>
FROM <table>
WHERE Column2 = '1234567'

UPDATE <table>
SET <allcolumns> = <allvalues>, etc etc
WHERE Column2 = '1234567'
```

If you want to just an UPDATE, then you would do something like:

```
var row = new Row();
// assuming a single column PK (id)
row.Column1 = '1';
row.Column2 = '1234567';
dbContext.Attach(row);
var entity = dbContext.Entity(entity);
entity.Property(e => e.Column2).IsModified = true;
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

produces exactly:

```
UPDATE <Table>
SET Column2 = '1234567'
WHERE Column1 = '1'
```

Answer (score 0):

// Note: ctx = your DbContext

```
  var tbl1 = (from t in ctx.Table1 where t.Id == 1234567 select t).FirstOrDefault();
  if (tbl1 != null) {
      tbl1.Column1 = "1";
      ctx.SaveChanges();

  }
```